# Compilation error in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone direct me to where exactly is the problem? Searched and can't figure it out.

When I open the browser this is the message I get:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Branch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 34:     
Line 35:     
Line 36:     public class _Page_Views_Home_index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<Branch>> {Line 37:Line 38: #line hidden
```

Comment: What is the root namespace of your project? It might needs to add it, e.g. `IEnumerable<RootNamespace.Branch>`

Comment: @TasosK. Awesome, Thanks!